# UWP Navigation between frames without losing Hamburger menu

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, navigation

So, I'm using MVVM Light. I have an UWP app where I have made a hamburger menu with buttons that loads a page into a Frame on the MainPage. The hamburger menu resides in the MainPage.

So far I've only used SourcePageType and binding it to a Type property in the MainPageViewModel. I can easily update the binding source of the SourcePageType by assigning the MainPageViewModel instance to a static property. That way I can do this for example:

```
MainPageViewModel.Current.CurrentFrame = typeof(NewItemPage);
```

However, that means I'm navigating between the frames just by updating the MainFrameViewModel, which is probably not optimal (losing out on GoBack for example).

The reason I did this is because whenever I use NavigateTo, I lose the Hamburger menu and I open a whole new page, which is not what I want. I want to keep the Hamburger menu available at all time.

It's also important that I can navigate from within the other pages as well, not just the MainPage. For instance, one of the pages is has a grid view of images, loaded from a database. Whenever I click on one of these images, I'm taken to for example a detail page or an edit page.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this using a NavigationService of some sort? I don't want to rely on just using the code-behind, since I want to learn mvvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following structure will help you

1. In your main `Frame` place XAML for `Hamburger` and another `Frame`(will contain all content which can be navigated and also act as main placeholder)
2. In your `NavigationService` have the reference to **content Frame** and load views inside it and navigate within them.

I have also done a similar thing in one of my applications and is working great.

Note- I assume that this much should help you, if you require further help please feel free to ask.

Comment: I already have a frame within the MainPage with the Hamburger menu that is meant for content. I assume I need to alter the NavigationService, because right now I only tried using the built-in navigationservice in MVVM Light. Should I make my own NavigationService class? Are there any good examples on how to do this?

Comment: Yes make your own NavigationService and then have reference of content frame to load views within it.

Comment: https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/implementing-viewmodel-based-navigation-in-your-universal-app/